# MathLink with Xcode 7.3

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, mac-os-x

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/MathLinkDevelopmentInC/MathLinkDevelopmentInC.pdf) tutorial to compile the example `addtwo` program.  But I am stuck on how to include the files
    `libMLi3.a`, `mathlink.h` and `mathlink.framework`
to the project.  Xcode seems to have changed enough since the tutorial was written (2008) that it's not clear how to add these files to the project.  (I am very familiar with how to write programs in C, but I'm much less familiar with Xcode)

More generally, is there an updated tutorial that explains how to write a C program with MathLink on Mac OS X 10.10+ with Xcode 7+ that will be called from the Mathematica kernel?

Comment: Why not do it from inside Mathematica instead of from Xcode? I use `CreateLibrary[]` and `LibraryFunctionLoad[]`. It seems to handle the compiling, including, linking, and loading honky-dory. See [this example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60879/94).

Comment: @MarkAdler any alternative that works is welcome.  But, I learn best by example; is there a short tutorial summarizing the steps to properly compile and link the `addtwo` program using `CreateLibrary[]` and `LibraryFunctionLoad[]`?  If not, would you write a short answer including one?

Comment: Did you consider [looking at the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.html)?

Comment: I think the tutorial you are trying is quite old. You can try following tutorial from mathematica documentation "tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Macintosh" and follow the section "Building Mac OS X WSTP Programs with Xcode".

Comment: @dsingh I didn't think that there would be an updated version of that page in Mathematica 10.4 (10.3 and earlier have the older instructions).  Thanks.  Would you please add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @QuantumDot I know it is not updated but the instructions provided in the tutorial will tell you how to include files in your xcode project as asked in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tutorial you are trying is quite old. You can try following tutorial from mathematica documentation "*tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Macintosh*" and follow the section "*Building Mac OS X WSTP Programs with Xcode*".The instructions provided in the tutorial will tell you how to include files in your xcode project as asked in the question.

Comment: I had written my reply as a comment originally but the user asked me to write it as an answer. Don't know why?.I have modified my answer to clarify my reply anyway.

Comment: I must have missed that. Apologies.